# Django Rest Framework Pagination Settings - Content-Range

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

**6.30.15 - HOW CAN I MAKE THIS QUESTION BETTER AND MORE HELPFUL TO OTHERS? FEEDBACK WOULD BE HELPFUL. THANKS!**

I am using DRF as server side to a Dojo/Dgrid web application. Dojo needs a content-range or range response from the server. Currently it doesn't send any and so the pagination for dgrid.grid isn't working properly.

[image]

In the DRF documentation it states" Pagination links that are included in response headers, such as Content-Range or Link." But doesn't give a clear process on HOW to set the DRF API to do this. I am still relatively new to web app development. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Including `Link` Header in response:**

To include a `Link` header in your response, you need to create a custom pagination serializer class, This should subclass `pagination.BasePagination` and override the `get_paginated_response(self, data)` method.

**Example (taken from [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#header-based-pagination)):**

Suppose we want to replace the default pagination output style with a modified format that includes the next and previous links in a `Link` header, we override the `get_paginated_response()` .

```
class LinkHeaderPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        next_url = self.get_next_link()
        previous_url = self.get_previous_link()

        if next_url is not None and previous_url is not None:
            link = '<{next_url}; rel="next">, <{previous_url}; rel="prev">'
        elif next_url is not None:
            link = '<{next_url}; rel="next">'
        elif previous_url is not None:
            link = '<{previous_url}; rel="prev">'
        else:
            link = ''

        link = link.format(next_url=next_url, previous_url=previous_url)
        headers = {'Link': link} if link else {}

        return Response(data, headers=headers)
```

After this, we need to include this pagination class in our settings so that it is used by DRF instead of the default pagination classes.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.apps.core.pagination.LinkHeaderPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

API responses for list endpoints will now include a `Link` header.

[image: pag]

**2. Including `Content-Range` Header in response:**

You can also send `Content-Range` header instead of `Link`. Just create a headers dictionary with `Content-Range` as the key and value as how many items are being returned and how many total items exist.

**For example:**

```
class ContentRangeHeaderPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        total_items = self.page.paginator.count
        item_starting_index = self.page.start_index() - 1 # In a page, indexing starts from 1
        item_ending_index = self.page.end_index() - 1

        content_range = 'items {0}-{1}/{2}'.format(item_starting_index, item_ending_index, total_items)      

        headers = {'Content-Range': content_range} 

        return Response(data, headers=headers)
```

Suppose this is the header received:

```
Content-Range: items 0-9/50
```

This tells us that the response has a `Content-Range` header with value as `items 0-9/50`. This indicates that first 10 items are returned out of total `50`.

You can also use `*` instead of total no. of items if calculating total is expensive.

```
Content-Range: items 0-9/* # Use this if total is expensive to calculate
```

Comment: What if you want it to give content-range instead of link. Dojo requests a range, not a link. This is helpful though!

Comment: You can do that also. Just create the `Content-Range` headers and pass it to the response. I have updated the ans.

Comment: I'm sorry - this is part is very new to me. Do you have any resources or examples of where someone has done this so I can SEE it, see what it looks like? I really appreciate your answers! What if the total value is always changing though?

Comment: I have added an example. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you @Rahul Gupta ... Been having this problem for the last 3 days

Answer (score 0):

DRF recommends a thirdparty package in its [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#link-header-pagination): [django-rest-framework-link-header-pagination](https://github.com/tbeadle/django-rest-framework-link-header-pagination)

It is supposed to follow the same path as the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/), which is basically the proper way of doing what the other answer suggest.

Here is a sample Link header taken from Github's API guide:

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user%3Amozilla&page=15>; rel="next",
  <https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user%3Amozilla&page=34>; rel="last",
  <https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user%3Amozilla&page=1>; rel="first",
  <https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user%3Amozilla&page=13>; rel="prev"
```

I haven't tried the package yet but I'll report back once done.