# Content-Range configuration for Django Rest Pagination

Tags: dojo, pagination, django-rest-framework, http-content-range

**6.30.15 - HOW CAN I MAKE THIS QUESTION BETTER AND MORE HELPFUL TO OTHERS? FEEDBACK WOULD BE HELPFUL. THANKS!**

I need to send a content-range header to a dojo/dgrid request: [image]

I cannot find any examples of HOW to do this. I'm not exactly sure where this setting goes (Content-Range: items 0-9/*). I have been given a great linkheaderpagination example on this question: [Django Rest Framework Pagination Settings - Content-Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898555/django-rest-framework-pagination-settings-content-range) But I don't know how to make this work to produce a Content-Range response. Any takers or does anyone know of any good resources or examples??

UPDATE: I am trying to create pagination in Dojo/grid. I have am using a server-side api (Django Rest Framework) to supply to data to the Dojo/Dgrid. Django Rest Framework does not automatically sent content-range headers when it gets a response from Dojo. Dojo sends a range request when formatted to have pagination. I don't know now to configure the Django Rest Framework API to send a content-range header when it gets a request from Dojo. Unfortunately, I'm trying to do something very specific and just general settings on either side doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more precise on what your problem is. Are you unable to set the header in dojo/dgrid or do you need help understanding the Content-Range header mechanics in general?

Comment: I added an update to the question to give more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about providing Content-Range in the response, I mentioned in [an answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606317/237950) (which I believe may also have originated from your team?) that there is one alternative to this header: if your response format is an object (not just an array of items), it can specify a `total` property indicating the total number of items instead.

Again looking for a few minutes at the [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles), it appears it should be possible to customize the format of the response.

Based on the docs and [reading the source of LimitOffsetPagination](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.1.3/rest_framework/pagination.py#L401-L407) (which you want to be using to work with dstore, as already discussed in a [previous question](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1145#issuecomment-110955485)), if I had to take a wild guess, you should be able to do the following server-side:

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('total', self.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('items', data)
        ]))
```

This purposely assigns the count to `total` and the data to `items` to align with the expectations of `dstore/Request`.  (`next` and `previous` are entirely unnecessary as far as dstore is concerned, so you could take or leave them, depending if you have any use for them elsewhere.)

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I was dancing all around this, I just couldn't figure out the exact formatting of it. Now I'm just trying to figure out where this class needs to go in order to point to it. The first question you referenced wasn't  from anyone on my team. The other two were me. Im the only one working on this part of the project - I've reached a point where no one else really knows what I'm trying to pull off. That's why I ask so many questions on here.

Comment: Ah, okay, my mistake on that then - the question just seemed so close to the same topic at the same time that it was uncanny. :) Meanwhile, would [commercial support](https://www.sitepen.com/support/index.html) be in the cards for you?  It seems like you've been fighting this battle inch by inch for a few weeks, and getting priority support (or outright custom development) from a team that specializes in this stuff could have potentially cut that timespan down dramatically.

Comment: I just took a longer look at that other question... that is a guy from our team. I apologize, I did a quick glance earlier and skimmed too quickly. Yeah, that was related to a different issue we were having at the time, when I couldn't get the grid to populate. He's was trying to help me some that day. He normally works on a different part of the project. So sorry about that!

Comment: I have attempted both of these answers. I'm getting data and the request is being sent. But I don't get response for either. I get the same thing from both of these answers. I'm not sure why django wont send the content-range response. I'm at a complete loss, I'm also not permitted to ask any more questions on SO for now either. Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 3):

**Including `Content-Range` Header in response:**

You just need to create a headers dictionary with `Content-Range` as the key and value as how many items are being returned and how many total items exist.

**For example:**

```
class ContentRangeHeaderPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    """
    A custom Pagination class to include Content-Range header in the
    response.
    """

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        """
        Override this method to include Content-Range header in the response.

        For eg.:
        Sample Content-Range header value received in the response for 
        items 11-20 out of total 50:

                Content-Range: items 10-19/50
        """

        total_items = self.page.paginator.count # total no of items in queryset
        item_starting_index = self.page.start_index() - 1 # In a page, indexing starts from 1
        item_ending_index = self.page.end_index() - 1

        content_range = 'items {0}-{1}/{2}'.format(item_starting_index, item_ending_index, total_items)      

        headers = {'Content-Range': content_range} 

        return Response(data, headers=headers)
```

Suppose this is the header received:

```
Content-Range: items 0-9/50
```

This indicates that first 10 items are returned out of total `50`.

**Note:** You can also use `*` instead of `total_items` if calculating total is expensive.

```
Content-Range: items 0-9/* # Use this if total is expensive to calculate
```

Comment: - I have attempted both of these. I'm getting data and the request is being sent. But I don't get response for either. I get the same thing from both of these answers. I'm not sure why django wont send the content-range response. I'm at a complete lost, I'm also not permitted to ask any more questions on SO for now either. Thank you for trying to help me.